# Subtracting Start TIME Values from Finish TIME Values and adding the values as a new column in CSV File in Unix

Tags: shell

I have a CSV file (output from a SQL Query). It has Start Time & Finish Time values given in different columns. I need to get the difference of Start Time and Finish Time and generate an HTML Report based on the difference value. For this, I wanted to include a new column, which will hold the output of "Finish Time" - "Start Time". columns are as below.
Time format is in the below format

```
START TIME: 2018-11-08 01:45:39.0
FINISH TIME:2018-11-06 06:48:20.0
```

I used below code, but I am not sure, whether its returning correct values. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Below are the 1st 3 lines of my CSV file

```
DESCRIPTION,SCHEDULE,JOBID,CLASSIFICATION,STARTTIME,FINISHTIME,NEXTRUNSTART,SYSTEM,CREATIONDATETIME,
DailyClearance,Everyday,XXXXXX, Standard,2018-11-08 01:59:59.0,2018-11-08 02:00:52.0,CAK-456,018-11-08 04:28:18,
Miscellinious,Everyday,XXXXXX, standart,2018-11-08 02:59:59.0,2018-11-08 03:29:39.0,2018-11-09 03:00:00.0,CAT-251,2018-11-08 04:28:18,
```

And this is my attempt

```
  awk 'NR==1 {$7 =  "DIFFMIN"} NR > 1 { $7 = $5 - $6} 1' <inputfile.csv
```

Comment: Can you give us a couple of lines from your CSV file?

Comment: Can you just adjust the SQL statement to include that value in its results, or do you not have control over that part of the workflow?

Comment: @Shawn: We don't have control over SQL Statement...

Comment: @kvantour: Below are the 1st 3 lines of the .csv file..                                                                                                              

DESCRIPTION,SCHEDULE,JOBID,CLASSIFICATION,STARTTIME,FINISHTIME,NEXTRUNSTART,SYSTEM,CREATIONDATETIME,
DailyClearance,Everyday,XXXXXX, Standard,2018-11-08 01:59:59.0,2018-11-08 02:00:52.0,CAK-456,018-11-08 04:28:18,
Miscellinious,Everyday,XXXXXX, standart,2018-11-08 02:59:59.0,2018-11-08 03:29:39.0,2018-11-09 03:00:00.0,CAT-251,2018-11-08 04:28:18,

Answer (score 0):

This might be of assistance to you. The idea is to use GNU awk which has time functions.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     (NR==1){print $0 OFS "DURATION"; next}
     { tstart = $5; tend = $6
       gsub(/[-:]/," ",tstart); tstart=mktime(tstart)
       gsub(/[-:]/," ",tend);   tend  =mktime(tend)
       $(NF+1)=tend-tstart;
       print
     }'
```

This should add the extra column. The time will be expressed in seconds.

The idea is to select the two columns and convert them into seconds since epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00). This is done using the `mktime` function which expects a string of the form `YYYY MM DD hh mm ss`. That is why we first perform a substitution. Once we have the seconds since epoch for the start and end-time, we can just subtract them to get the duration in seconds.

**note:** there might be some problems during daylight saving time. This depends on the settings of your system.

**note:** subsecond accuracy is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have used the script you have mentioned, but its throwing the below mentioned error .                                                                                                               awk: cmd. line:3:        gsub ([-:]," ",tstart); tstart=mktime(tstart)
     awk: cmd. line:3:              ^ syntax error                                             awk: cmd. line:3: fatal: 0 is invalid as number of arguments for gsub

Comment: I have made below change to the script you have mentioned and its working now.Only thing is, the last column doesn't have an header.                                                                                                        gsub("-:"," ",tstart); tstart=mktime(tstart)
  gsub("-:"," ",tend);   tend  =mktime(tend)

Comment: @D.Joe I have updated the script to include the header